# Tab is not indenting selected text

Tags: linux, intellij-idea, virtualbox, centos6

I want to select multiple lines of code and indent them with [TAB] but this is not working.

- The opposite of it, to shift it to the left side with [Ctrl]+[TAB] works.
- The problem occurs in IntelliJ IDEA 14.01 but not in other programs ("Gedit" for example).
- It is no problem to indent a single line of code by placing the cursor at the beginning of the line.
- I'm working in a CentOS 6.2 VM (VirtualBox) on a Windows 7 machine.

Answer (score 2):

I found out, that the "VIM Emulator" is causing those effects. 
Tools --> Vim Elmuator (toggle on/off) OR Ctrl+Alt+V

Answer (score 0):

As `@Sailcomp` pointed out the IdeaVim plugin is what causes the problem.

However if you take a look [at Vim's wiki](http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Shifting_blocks_visually) it explains how to indent/unindent using `>>` and `<<` respectively. Along with the `.` command to repeat.